# dynamic array of ref in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

in my portaflio iam trying to make a ref for my projects card but I want it to be dynamic not a Collection of static ref ,in the parent component I am made function that take ref from the card component but I getting errors here is the code and error
parent component :

```
function Projects() {
  let imagesRef = useRef([]);
  let [projectCard, setProjectCard] = useState([]);

  let addrefitem = (img) => {
    imagesRef.current.push(img);
    console.log(imagesRef.current);
  };

  let showprojects = (start, end) => {
    let show = [];

    for (let i = start; i < end; i++) {
      //there will be one data more if this is disable
      if (i <= data.length - 1) {
        show.push(<ProjectCard {...data[i]} ref={addrefitem} />);
      }
    }

    setProjectCard(show);
  };
return (
    <Box component={"section"} className="projects" id="projects">
      <Container maxWidth={"xl"}>
        {/*Heading*/}
        <Box>
          <Typography variant="h4" color="#fff" textAlign={"center"}>
            My Projects {<GrReactjs />}
          </Typography>
          <Typography variant="body1" color="#fff">
            this is my projects made with js&React {<GrReactjs />}
          </Typography>
        </Box>
        {/* project tab bar*/}
        <ProjectCardtab
          tabclickhandler={tabclickhandler}
          tabscount={tabscount}
        />
        {/* cards */}
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <Grid container className="data-card-container" sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
            {projectCard}
          </Grid>
        </ThemeProvider>
      </Container>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

part of card component

```
function ProjectCard({...},ref) {

return (
//code 

  <img
          style={{ opacity: 0 }}
          className="img"
          loading="lazy"
          src={require(`../../assets/img/project_image/${imgurl}`)}
          alt="image of project"
          ref={ref}
        />

)
export default React.forwardRef(ProjectCard);
```

error :
[image: img of errors]

my goal is to make a good image loading effect and part of it is that when picture is done loading it show

Comment: You can store refs using createRef. Example

 ```const refs = useRef(
    Array.from({length: 5}).map(() => React.createRef()),
  )```

and in ProjectCard you can use forwardRef to pass ref as prop.

Comment: i forget to mention that but I am using forwardref : `export default React.forwardRef(ProjectCard);`

Comment: Then add comma if you are using forward ref,```function ProjectCard({...props}, ref)``` to avoid getting that ref is not a prop error

Comment: it work now but didnt fix the error I need another way to save the ref in side the useeref instead of 
` let addrefitem = (img) => {  imagesRef.current.push(img);}`
I try to search on youtube but all I found was static and the only one work give this error

Answer (score 0):

The way you spreading the props are creating the error you can pass the props by defining the `ref` and spreading the other props `...otherProps` and they should be in the curly bracket.

```
function ProjectCard({ ref, ...otherProps }) {
```

Comment: the error was in console.log

Comment: I have given you the `ref` error you getting in my solution, and the other two errors; the `key` warning, you can add `key="any_random_key"` to `show.push(<ProjectCard key="random_key" {...data[i]} ref={addrefitem} />);`, and `Context` worning as the error suggests to you, use `Context.Provider` and `Context.Consume`